# How to bring origin/master to latest commit without pushing to remote?

Tags: git

I want to make this happen without any pushing to the remote repository.

From this: `commit (HEAD -> master)`

```
        `commit (origin/master)`
```

To : `commit (HEAD -> master, origin/master)`

Comment: I don't understand the output you wrote, I answered based on the title you gave to the post. Let me know if it doesn't make sens

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please give an example with commits IDs and a branch representation maybe.

Comment: Do you want your HEAD and local `master` branch to be at the same commit than `origin/master` ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. If you  updates the `origin/master` it will be out of sync with the remote repository's `master`. Thus a fetch or pull will make a forced updated to the 'local' remote ref.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. Actually I need to make my HEAD, master and origin/master in the same commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to revert to a previous commit.

```
git reset --hard <commit_hash>
```

Be careful while doing this. You may lose commits that are between `(HEAD -> master)` and `<commit_hash>`

Answer (score 0):

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master <sha1_of_the_commit_you_want>
```

Updates the given ref (here `origin/master`, of its complete name `refs/remotes/origin/master`) to point the given commit.
`update-ref` will only change a local ref (`refs/remotes/origin/master` is a local ref) and does no network call, nothing changes on the actual remote.
This can work for local branches too, like `master` (complete name `refs/heads/master`).

Note that `origin/master` will be re-synced on your next fetch (or pull, which includes a fetch)

Comment: Please explain what this command does for people who don't know it ;)